# How can I transform a point from world space to object space?

Tags: mathematics, graphics, matrix, geometry

If I have an object space described by transformation matrix that should be applied to object to transform it to world space, what I have to do to transform point (world space) to that object space.

I guess it's more of a math question, but I believe gamedevs are more familiar with terminology.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a matrix that transforms from object to world space, the inverse of that matrix will transform a world space value to object space.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the details of that transform matrix? Or point me to somewhere that explains it? I'm trying to solve a similar problem.

Comment: It isn't that simple.  You cannot easily invert a 4x4 matrix with rotate scale and translate components.

Comment: Well, it's just math.  But it's a lot of math, and it's not trivial or intuitive math.  Most math libraries will supply a matrix inversion function for you.  If so, you just call that.  If you're writing your own math routines, my 4x4 matrix invert function is [here](https://github.com/vectorstorm/vectorstorm/blob/master/VS/Math/VS_Matrix.cpp), in the function named "vsMatrix4x4::InverseGeneral()".  Feel free to use/adapt.

Answer (score 6):

You need to keep around the components of how you built your `world` matrix to begin with.

Say your world matrix is for a spinning coin.  So, it has `rotate`, `scale`, then `translate` in that order.

Let's assume you're using row-major matrices.  You'd form your forward transformation matrix as:

```
matrix = rotate(30,60,90) * Scale(5) * Translate ( 5, 0, 0 )
```

Form the backwards (inverse) transformation as just the opposite operations, in the opposite order.

```
inv_matrix = Translate( -5, 0, 0 ) * Scale( 1.0/5.0 ) * TRANSPOSE( rotate(30,60,90) )
```

So note a few things:

- inverse of rotation matrix ("unrotate") is just its transpose.  (this is a **special** property of rotation matrices only and doesn't apply to other matrix types)
- inverse of scale matrix (unscale) is 1/scale
- inverse of translation matrix is applying -translate